load image in an compose multi platform app using org.jetbrains.skiko
i'm new in compose multiplatform. i want to convert byte array to compose bitmap. when i create the project with kmp.jetbrains and open it in android studio by default it has the library of Gradle: org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko-iosarm64:0.8.15 in iosMain but not for androidMain and commonMain .
when i want to add it for common and android i add : org.jetbrains.skiko:skiko:0.8.15
but it is not acted like i expect .
here is my BitmapUtit.kt:
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asComposeImageBitmap
import org.jetbrains.skia.Bitmap
import org.jetbrains.skia.Image

   @Composable
fun rememberBitmapFromBytes(bytes: ByteArray?): ImageBitmap? {
    return remember(bytes) {
        if (bytes != null) {
            Bitmap.makeFromImage(Image.makeFromEncoded(bytes)).asComposeImageBitmap()
        } else null
    }
}

it is ok if i put it in iosMain but when i put it in androidMain and commonMain the asComposeImageBitmap() is unknown and red.

as i searched it seems that asComposeImageBitmap() is only available in iosMain module . so we should define separate files .
in commonMain:
@Composable
expect fun rememberBitmapFromBytes(bytes: ByteArray?):ImageBitmap?

in iosMain:
@Composable
actual fun rememberBitmapFromBytes(bytes: ByteArray?): ImageBitmap? {
    return remember(bytes) {
        if (bytes != null) {
            Bitmap.makeFromImage(Image.makeFromEncoded(bytes)).asComposeImageBitmap()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}

in androidMain:
@Composable
actual fun rememberBitmapFromBytes(bytes: ByteArray?): ImageBitmap? {
    return remember(bytes) {
        if (bytes != null) {
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.size).asImageBitmap()
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}

so the org.jetbrains.skiko can just be used in ios module
